# Python не видит список в строке csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Хочу прочитать заголовки файла csv, выполняю:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    heads = next(reader)
for head in heads:
    print(head)
```

А в итоге получаю один элемент:

```
    Country Name, "Country Code", ..... "2017",
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос через кнопку `править` пример вашего csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV могут отличаться друг от друга, например разделителями, поэтому код автора мог неправильно вытащить строки, [используя стандартные настройки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params).

Привожу пример CSV с разделителем полей `,` (запятая).

foo.csv:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
1965,Пиксель,E240 – формальдегид (опасный консервант)!,"красный, зелёный, битый","3000,00"
1965,Мышка,"А правильней использовать ""Ёлочки""",,"4900,00"
"Н/д",Кнопка,Сочетания клавиш,"MUST USE! Ctrl, Alt, Shift","4799,00"
```

Код:

```
import csv

with open('foo.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    headers = next(reader)
    print('Headers:', headers)
    
    print('Rows:')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```